# How to be DRY with geb?

Tags: groovy, geb

I find I keep having to repeat myself with GEB asserts.

For example this is needed before many of my asserts:

```
browser.$("h3", text: "Example Error Response").siblings("div").find("pre", 'data-language':'javascript')
```

What's the pattern for saving a lookup specification that can then be re-used?

Remember that the lookup is to go with an "assert", so it has to be executed when the browser is in a particular state (i.e. I can't do the lookup once and save the result).

For context, here's a complete example:

```
Given(~'I should see the example error response on the page') { ->
     assert browser.$("h3", text: "Example Error Response").siblings("div").find("pre", 'data-language':'javascript').text() =~ /\}/
     assert browser.$("h3", text: "Example Error Response").siblings("div").find("pre", 'data-language':'javascript').text() =~ /\{/
}
```

Comment: Are you using pages? And I assume this is cucumber? Have you looked at https://github.com/geb/geb-example-cucumber-jvm

Comment: I'm new to groovy and this complete stack, and have just been handed an existing project to deal with.  I don't believe it's using pages.  It is cucumber.  However, I've found a solution which I'll post as an answer.  Thanks for the link to the GEB example (but it uses pages, whatever that is!?!).

Comment: Just had a look at Pages, and seems like a good way to go.  I'll put on that on the TO DO list for a future refactor.

Answer (score 0):

To be DRY, I'm now doing this:

```
class   ExampleErrorResponse {
   static Object get(browser) {
        return browser.$("h3", text: "Example Error Response").siblings("div").find("pre", 'data-language':'javascript');
    }
}
```

which I can use like this:

```
Given(~'I should see the example error response on the page') { ->
  assert ExampleErrorResponse.get(browser).text() =~ /\}/
  assert ExampleErrorResponse.get(browser).text() =~ /\{/
}
```

Please comment if you see any problems/gotchas with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Feels like you should use Geb's [built-in support for the Page Object pattern](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/#the-page-object-pattern-2) to fulfil your requirements.